# javascript condiciones y almacenamiento en variables

Tags: javascript

buenas tardes tengo una duda como puedo hacer para  guardar el formato de un hora en una variable me explico
tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
//creo un evento para extraer los datos de la base de dato y mostrarlos en el modal
var hora1=04:00:00;// almaceno dos horas que necesito comparar 
var hora2=07:00:00;
//extraigo la informacion de la columna seleccionada
var date_start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var time_start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('hh:mm:ss');

$time_start= $('#modal-event #_time_start').val(time_start);
//almaceno la  informacion en una variable que time_start para luego compararla con las variables anterior mencionadas

$('#modal-event #delete').attr('data-id', event.id);
$('#modal-event #_title').val(event.title);
$('#modal-event #_placa').val(event.placa);
$('#modal-event #_date_start').val(date_start);
$('#modal-event #_time_start').val(time_start);

if ($time_start >  hora1 && $time_start  < hora2 ) {
   alert('pedido invalido debe Modificar la hora');
}else{
   alert('Pedido Valido');
}
 console.log(time_start);
 $('#modal-event').modal('show');     
 }
```

Pero la cuestion es que siempre toma la variable mal  no se si es la condicion o es la forma en como almaceno la hora en la variable:

Comment: La hora no es un tipo elemental que puedas escribir así. Podrías usar la clase Date, pero creo que en tu caso te bastaría con usar cadenas: `"07:00:00"`, donde las comillas son la gran diferencia con tu código.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript no cuenta con un tipo de objeto para hora, de hecho al usar

```
var hora1=04:00:00
```

Esto genera un error. Ejemplo al usar lo anterior en Stack Snippet gener el error "unexpected token :"

```js
var hora1=04:00:00;
console.info(typeof hora1);
```

Esto es porque en JavaScript los dos puntos se utilizan para asignar etiquetas ([label](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/label)) a sentencias así como también en la sentencia [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) para delimitar los valores a comparar la expresión (`case valor:`).

En lugar de

```
var hora1=04:00:00;
```

podrías usar

```
var hora1='04:00:00';
```

Y luego extraer cada parte o bien desde un principio usa una variable para cada componente, horas, minutos y segundos.

Answer (score 0):

la solucion para la pregunta era convertir la variable en un string la que estaba extrayendo de la base de datos para luego poder comparla con una  hora que se asignara como  muestro a continuacion

```
 var hora1 = '04:00:00';
 var hora2 = '07:00:00';

var time_start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('hh:mm:ss');

var f = time_start.toString();
```

para luego poder hacer la condicion y comparar los dos string

```
if (f > hora1 && f < hora2 ) {
   alert('pedido invalido debe Modificar la hora');
   console.log(f, "es mayor a", hora1);
}else{
   alert('Pedido Valido');
   console.log(f, "es menor a", hora1);
}
```